# Using Cross Joins individually

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying this statement:

```
 Declare @Param1 int = 0
 SELECT @Param1,T.N
  CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(1),(2)) as T(N)
```

Returns this error:

**Msg 156, Level 15, State 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CROSS'.**

It seems I can only use this Cross Join when I use `FROM` first, but not by itself?

Comment: `CROSS JOIN` is one of the several types of join. All joins can appear only in the `FROM` clause, nowhere else. And your query does not have a `FROM`, so it's not valid SQL anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess when you do it like this it works:

```
SELECT @Param1,T.N
FROM (VALUES(0),(1),(2)) as T(N)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you cannot do a join outside of a from statement.  Use a table var for param and join it?

```
Declare @Param1 table(param1 int);
insert into @param1 values(0)
 SELECT *
 from @Param1
CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(1),(2)) as T(N);
```